# JSR310 when to use which classes?

Tags: java-time, jsr310

I would like to verify if my understanding of JSR310 classes use-cases are correct, below a diagram with classes, and how i see them fit:

```
   Database (UTC)
       ||
       \/
  OffsetDateTime      (used in persistence or transmission, databases and XML)
       ||
       \/
    Instant            (used in business logic, for date time calculations)
       ||
       \/
   ZonedDateTime  <-- ZoneId  (used in presentation layer, requiring the client zoneId)
       ||
       \/
    LocalDateTime (used in presentation layer, obtained from ZonedDateTime)
       ||
       \/
     Front-end
```

My uncertainity its related with ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime, since as far as i understand are both suitable for presentation layer, altough LocalDatetime does not have time-zone or offset.

Its the LocalDateTime what i should send to front-end, after ZonedDateTime has handled all DST conversions and anomalies?

Do i not send a ZonedDateTime to front-end since it has extra information like time-zone?

thanks in advance

Comment: For most purposes I would still send `ZonedDateTime` to the presentation layer and leave to that layer whether to format it with or without UTC offset and/or time zone (e.g., time zone abbreviation). If you know the user’s time zone you may argue that it is not necessary.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes in this case we know the users time-zone. But its a good point.

Answer (score 1):

JSR310 is the Java specification for the java.time package, which provides classes for date and time manipulation in Java. The main classes in the package are:

- `LocalDate`: Represents a date without a time (year, month, and day)
- `LocalTime`: Represents a time without a date (hours, minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds)
- `LocalDateTime`: Represents a date and time without a time zone (combines LocalDate and LocalTime)
- `ZonedDateTime`: Represents a date and time with a time zone
- `Instant`: Represents a point in time (similar to java.util.Date)

You should use `LocalDate` when you only need to represent a date, `LocalTime` when you only need to represent a time, `LocalDateTime` when you need to represent both date and time but without timezone, `ZonedDateTime` when you need to represent both date and time with timezone and `Instant` when you need to represent a point in time.

Comment: Yes usually clients dont require to see UTC offset or Timezone in front-end. So it hink Locals are more suitable for this layer.